# Installing python interpreter inside of the project files on macOS

Tags: python, macos

I just started working on macos system and encountered the first issue.

I need to have local python interpreter inside of the project directory and I don't know how to achieve this on macos.
So basically I would need to have python interpreter inside of this path:

```
/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project_name
```

Normally on windows, I would just unzip downloaded files to this directory and inside of PyCharm set this local interpreter as project interpreter.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thu is a bit unclear. Why would you need to do this? And why wouldn't to use a virtualenv?

Comment: PyCharm should still work the same way... You would set the "working directory", though, not the interpreter within a specific project (unless using venv)

Comment: This is how the other developer wanted this project to be. An interpreter is delivered with the project and it handles everything - no .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PyCharm you can just open Settings|Project Interpreter, then click on the star button on the right and choose "Add..". In the opened window you will be able to specify location of the environment.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how can I download/install physically interpreter on mac in this specific project directory, so then I could add it inside of pycharm project settings as a project interpreter.

Comment: First you need to install python and then you'll be able to create an environment.

Comment: How can I install python interpreter in this specific directory on macos?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a `virtual environment`.

[This guide](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#managing-virtual-environments-with-virtualenvwrapper) can walk you through the setup and details of how virtual environments work.

When you're ready to go, navigate to the path you want to install a virtual environment in (`/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project_name` in your case) and run the command `virtualenv venv`.  This will result in a virutal environment in a subfolder called `venv`.  Beneath that, Python is under the `bin` folder

Comment: But it needs to be in directory "python" inside of project files so that you can run python commands from the js code that this project consists of. In windows it's project_name/python/python.exe

Comment: Actually, when you create a venv you'll find a python3 inside a bin folder of venv directory.

Comment: Ok, let me be more clear:
I need to install python interpreter inside of the project in /Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project_name/python/python(executable here)
How can I do this?

Comment: I don't really understand why you need it but you can just create a link with "ls" command in your project directory to an already installed python interpreter.

Comment: @MikhailBerlinkov makes a good point.  Since you're using unix, you can make a symlink wherever you'd like.  He mentions the `ls` command, but I think he meant `ln -s`.  Here's a how-to:  https://www.howtogeek.com/297721/how-to-create-and-use-symbolic-links-aka-symlinks-on-a-mac/